# How do I start a clock after a delay of 5ns?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In my project, I need two separate clocks, but one of them, `bit_clk` needs to be started after a delay of 5ns. How can I do that?

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
always #40 clk =~ clk;
always #5 bit_clk =~ bit_clk;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can delay the start of a clock by using a `forever` loop inside an `initial` block:

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps

module tb;

bit clk, bit_clk;

always #40 clk =~ clk;

initial begin
    #5; // Delay before starting
    forever #5 bit_clk =~ bit_clk;
end

endmodule
```